# fill an array based on an object and another array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of sentences and an object that its properties point to each sentence index and the values that represent the score of the sentence like this:

```
var sentences = ['I am', 'I am a good doctor', 'I am a doctor', 'I am a']; // sentence with index 0 score 10 and sentence with index 3 score 90 .   
var object = { 0: 10, 1: 100, 2: 80, 3: 90}; // index of sentences with their scores
```

if I want to create an array named `result` to store the index of sentences with lower scores and ignore the sentence index with the highest score then I can do something like this:

```js
    var object = {0: 10, 1: 100, 2: 80, 3: 90},
        max = Math.max(...Object.values(object)),
        result = Object
            .keys(object)
            .filter(k => object[k] !== max)
            .map(Number);
    
    console.log(result);
```

The code above works fine until we have more than one highest value like this (equal and highest):

```
var object = {0: 10, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100};
```

This time `result` array returns only `[0]` and we lose all equal and highest ones.

I want to modify the code so that if we encountered this situation then only the sentence with **longer length** will be removed.

So in our example `sentences[1] = 'I am a good doctor'` is the longest among indexes of 1, 2 and 3 then we just remove it and the final result would be :

```
result = [0, 2, 3]
```

I have tried a lot but no matter how much I try, at last, I just get more confused...:(

Comment: What if there will be 2 or more sentences with the same length?

Comment: There is not... I promise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `sort` method, and then discard the item sorted at the high-end:

```js
var sentences = ['I am', 'I am a good doctor', 'I am a doctor', 'I am a'];
var object = { 0: 10, 1: 100, 2: 80, 3: 90};

var result = Object.keys(object).map(Number)
                   .sort((i, j) => object[i] - object[j] || 
                                   sentences[i].length - sentences[j].length);
result.pop(); // discard last
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must keep the data like it is then try this. I used the suggestion made by @Daniyal Lukmanov in my answer.

```
var sentences = ['I am', 'I am a good doctor', 'I am a doctor', 'I am a'];
var object = {0: 10, 1: 80, 2: 100, 3: 100};

maxScore = Math.max(...Object.values(object));

var maxScoreSentences = [];

for (var i=0; i <sentences.length; i++){
  if(object[i] === maxScore) {
    maxScoreSentences.push(sentences[i]);
  }
}

lengthsMax = Math.max(...maxScoreSentences.map(s => s.length));

result = Object
    .keys(object)
    .filter(k => object[k] !== maxScore || sentences[k].length !== lengthsMax)
    .map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer plus one but I want the structure too :)

Comment: You're looking for the max length of the sentences with the max score, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just add checking `lengths` maximum too:

```js
var sentences = ['I am', 'I am a good doctor', 'I am a doctor', 'I am a'];

var object = {0: 10, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100},
lengthsMax = Math.max(...sentences.map(s => s.length)),
max = Math.max(...Object.values(object)),
result = Object
    .keys(object)
    .filter(k => object[k] !== max || sentences[k].length !== lengthsMax)
    .map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer plus one but try this: `var object = {0: 10, 1: 80, 2: 100, 3: 100},` ... the maximum length should be between equal highest values! Not maximum length of all sentences

Answer (score 1):

Result you want is the concatenation of results with score less then max & results with score equal to max.

```js
const sentences = ['I am', 'I am a good doctor', 'I am a doctor', 'I am a'];
const object = {0: 10, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100};
const max = Math.max(...Object.values(object));
const objectKeys =  Object.keys(object);

const equalValues = objectKeys.map((k,i) => object[k] === max ? sentences[i].length : 0);

const lengthsMax = Math.max(...equalValues);
const resultEqualToMax  = objectKeys
    .filter((k,i) => object[k] === max && sentences[i].length !== lengthsMax)   
    .map(Number);
const resultLessThenMax = objectKeys
    .filter(k => object[k] !== max)
    .map(Number);
const result = [...resultLessThenMax,...resultEqualToMax];
console.log(result);
```